# How is a Bulb mode enabled for a Canon EOS 70D?

Tags: long-exposure, camera-controls, canon-70d, bulb-mode

I've owned a Canon EOS 70D for two weeks, but when I wanted to make a long exposure of the Geminid meteors I couldn't find the BULB Mode. Only a maximum of 30s shutter speed.

So my question is: Is there actually a Bulb Mode on the 70d?

ps: I'd shoot at "M" mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the online manual, the B on the mode dial will set it to Bulb mode. Have a look at page 24 in [this document](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300012004/03/EOS_70D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf).

[image: 70D Mode dial]

Comment: Ah, allright. Thanks! Also thanks for the great manual. :)

Comment: @MikaldL no problems - there should be a printed version in the box your camera came with.

Comment: There was, but not this version which contains more information about the camera.

Comment: The full instruction manual is included in PDF form on the **EOS Camera Instruction Manuals Disk (DVD-ROM)** that should have also been in the box with your camera.